# How to change Visual Studio to not ignore whitespaces at begin of line

Tags: visual-studio

I want to see all differences in file (include new whitespaces) when comparing with checked in Code.

For Example `"<html>....."` and `" <html>....."` or `"</html>"` and `"</html> "`
Is there any way to enable this?

Comment: let's say a is a string with "<html>.." and b is another string with " <html>.."
do you want them both to be the same or different?

Comment: I want it should be different

Comment: what have you tried so far? post your code as well so we can see what's wrong in there

Comment: I tryed to find an option inside Visual Studio